# How come Jane's Aiúa doesn't need to be on the new starships anymore?

Tags: enders-game, orson-scott-card

I'm reading Children of the Mind right now, and when I read,

> As the hovercar carried them toward Milagre, the human town, they passed near some of the dozens of starships currently in service. The work of migration didn’t take the night off. Stevedores—many of them pequeninos—were loading supplies and equipment for transport. Families were shuffling in lines to fill up whatever spaces were left in the cabins. Jane would be getting no rest tonight as she took box after box Outside and back In.

That seems to imply that Jane doesn't need Ender or young Val or Peter on the ship in order to transport it, but in Xenocide we learned that it would only work if they were there. I can't find the exact place, but it's implied here:

> “Leave?” offered Miro. “You get your wish. Peter will soon be gone—Jane can pilot a ship with him aboard. No doubt the same thing will be possible with young Val.

Contradiction? Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was never stated explicitly that Jane couldn't move the ships without Ender or his aiúa being present.  The first assays Outside in *Xenocide* were experiments.  Jane thought she needed Ender and Miro to be aboard ship for the first attempt because she was philotically twined with them.  But no one knew for sure and it seemed to increase the odds of success for the recolada experiment for the two of them to go along.  If Jane needed a security blanket, why not let her have it?  Later in *Xenocide* Jane tried moving a ship with just young Peter aboard (no Miro) and it worked, which meant that she was wrong about needing Ender and Miro.  This also suggested that Jane might progress to moving ships without Ender or some other philotic familiar aboard, which apparently happened by the time the events of *Children of the Mind* took place.

Comment: Wasn't there also a test somewhere with a single formic?  I vaguely recall that.  My memory isn't so hot though.